# Load Custom URI Scheme with response.sendRedirect

Tags: java, ios, spring, servlets, uri

I am trying to load a customer URI scheme after a callback from thirdparty Oauth to close the webview initiated for authorization from the app. I tried 
response.sendRedirect("myapp://myapp.com"); 
which did not do anything. I am using Java and Spring.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.

```
request.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/myapp://myapp.com").forward(request, response);
```